# Gtk: build Gtk libs in Mavericks (Apple Mac OS) by compiling source code

Tags: macos, gtk2

I would like to use Gtk libs in a mac laptop. Its operation system is Mavericks. For my program, I don't care about Mac look and feel. For compiling my program, I don't like graphical interface but prefer to `gcc` and `make` command line tools (Linux style). Therefore, I don't want to install Gtk libs by installing Xcode (a monster taking too much space) plus port Gtk by macport. I prefer to compile source code to install Gtk libs. Followed are my steps.

1. Build `gcc` and `make` by installing Xcode command line tools  `commandlinetoolsosx10.9forxcode6.2.dmg` from Apple Developer Website.
2. Build `X` development environment by installing `XQuartz-2.7.8.dmg` since X11 doesn't ship with Mac OS any more.
3. Download Gtk source packages and all its dependencies. I would install the packages in the order followed.

`zlib-1.2.8 -> pkg-config-0.29 -> jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz -> libpng-1.6.18 -> tiff-4.0.6 -> libiconv-1.14 -> gettext-0.19.6 -> freetype-2.6 -> fontconfig-2.11.94 -> libffi-3.2.1 -> pixman-0.33.4 -> cairo-1.14.4 -> glib-2.47.1 ->  pango-1.38.1 -> atk-2.18.0 -> gdk-pixbuf-2.33.1 -> gtk+-2.24.28`

4. Build environment variables for compilation.

   ```
   GTK_DIR="$HOME/gtk"
   CPPFLAGS="-I$GTK_DIR/include"
   LDFLAGS="-L$GTK_DIR/lib"
   PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$GTK_DIR/lib/pkgconfig"
   export CPPFLAGS LDFLAGS PKG_CONFIG_PATH

   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$GTK_DIR/lib"
   PATH="$GTK_DIR/bin:$PATH"
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH PATH
   ```
5. The compilation for package `pkg-config-0.29`

   ```
   LDFLAGS="-framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon"  
   ./configure --with-internal-glib --prefix=$GTK_DIR   
   make  
   make install
   ```
6. The compilation for package `gtk+-2.24.28`

   ```
   CPPFLAGS="-I$GTK_DIR/include -I$GTK_DIR/include/cairo -I$GTK_DIR/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I$GTK_DIR/include/pango-1.0 -I$GTK_DIR/include/atk-1.0 -I$GTK_DIR/include/freetype2 -I$GTK_DIR/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I$GTK_DIR/include/glib-2.0 -I$GTK_DIR/lib/glib-2.0/include"  
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$GTK_DIR/lib"
   ./configure --prefix=$GTK_DIR   
   make  
   make install
   ```
7. The compilation for `other` packages

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$GTK_DIR/lib"  
   ./configure --prefix=$GTK_DIR   
   make  
   make install
   ```
8. The compilation for all packages except the last one `gtk+-2.24.28` made it. The error when compiling gtk+-2.24.28 is

   ```
   /bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -export-dynamic -framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon -L/Users/wu/gtk/lib -o builder builder.o ../../gdk/libgdk-x11-2.0.la ../../gtk/libgtk-x11-2.0.la -L/usr/X11/lib -lXrender -lX11    -lm 
   libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -o .libs/builder builder.o  -L/Users/wu/gtk/lib ../../gdk/.libs/libgdk-x11-2.0.dylib -L/usr/X11/lib ../../gtk/.libs/libgtk-x11-2.0.dylib /Users/wu/Downloads/gtk/src/gtk+-2.24.28/gdk/.libs/libgdk-x11-2.0.dylib -lXinerama /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libgthread-2.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib -lresolv /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libffi.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libcairo.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libpixman-1.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libfontconfig.dylib -lexpat /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libfreetype.dylib -lbz2 /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libpng16.dylib -lz -lSM -lICE -lXext /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libgmodule-2.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libintl.dylib /Users/wu/gtk/lib/libiconv.dylib -lc -lXrender -lX11 -lm -pthread -framework ApplicationServices -framework Carbon -framework CoreFoundation
   clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
     "_atk_object_ref_relation_set", referenced from:
         _test_widget in builder.o
     "_atk_relation_get_relation_type", referenced from:
         _test_widget in builder.o
     "_atk_relation_get_type", referenced from:
         _test_widget in builder.o
     "_atk_relation_set_get_n_relations", referenced from:
         _test_widget in builder.o
     "_atk_relation_set_get_relation", referenced from:
         _test_widget in builder.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   make[4]: *** [builder] Error 1
   make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   make: *** [all] Error 2
   ```

The error is a linking error about `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`. I googled the error and the suggestion is to set the right architecture in Xcode GUI. But it doesn't help since I don't have Xode GUI at all in laptop.

I also tried `CC="gcc -arch i386"`, neither did it work. And I tried `LDFLAGS="-framework CoreFoundation -framework Carbon -L$GTK_DIR/lib"`, neither did it work. For the last two try, I only recompiled the packages from cairo-1.14.4 to gtk+-2.24.28, not all the packages.

Any clues? Please help. Thank you.

Edit: using atk-2.20 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same; adding `-latk-1.0` to the LDFLAGS fixed the problem.  It seems that the autotools/gcc/whatever is missing some lib/include flags.  I have no idea why this is, but adding them in manually when calling `./configure` works fine.

I think in this case that the complaint about the architecture is just a red herring.